# Calculate time difference between two records and insert into another table if difference is greater than 30 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

**Tran_DeviceAttRec table:**

```
Emp_id  Card_Number Dev_Id  Dev_Direction   Punch_RawDate           sno_id    
    1       1           1   IN              2021-02-01 16:52:26.000 331
    2       2           1   IN              2021-02-01 16:52:48.000 332
    2       2           2   OUT             2021-02-01 16:52:54.000 333
    3       3           1   IN              2021-02-01 16:58:01.000 334
    4       4           1   IN              2021-02-01 16:58:46.000 335
    3       3           2   OUT             2021-02-01 16:59:02.000 336
    4       4           2   OUT             2021-02-01 18:25:00.000 338
    1       1           2   OUT             2021-02-01 18:26:00.000 339
```

I want to select and insert only those fields which time difference is more than 30 second into temp table
for example if emp_id 2 punchdate is 2021-02-01 16:52:48.000 and Dev_direction is IN
and the same emp_id 2 punchdate is 2021-02-01 16:52:54.000 and Dev_direction is OUT then it should not select and insert value to temp table

**TempTable:**

```
Emp_id  Card_Number Dev_Id  Dev_Direction   Punch_RawDate           sno_id
1       1           2       OUT             2021-02-01 18:26:00.000 339
3       3           2       OUT             2021-02-01 16:59:02.000 336
4       4           2       OUT             2021-02-01 18:25:00.000 338
```

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. I tried following queries to find the time but I don't know how to calculate the difference between time

```
SELECT TOP 1 Emp_id, Punch_RawDate
FROM Tran_DeviceAttRec
where Dev_Direction = 'OUT'
ORDER BY sno_id DESC

SELECT TOP 1 Emp_id, Punch_RawDate
from Tran_DeviceAttRec
where Dev_Direction = 'IN' and Emp_id = 1
order by sno_id desc
```

Comment: Have you considered `lag`?

Comment: no, because i don't have to compare with the previous row. The previous row may have some other employee data

Comment: Surely when you say "which time difference is more than 30 second" you are comparing the current row to a previous row of the same employee? Which is exactly what you use `lag` for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select and insert only those fields which time difference is more than 30 second into temp table for example

Do you just want `lag()`?

```
select dar.*
from (select dar.*,
             lag(Punch_RawDate) over (partition by emp_id order by Punch_RawDate) as prev_Punch_RawDate
      from Tran_DeviceAttRec dar
     ) dar
where dar.Punch_RawDate > dateadd(second, 30, prev_Punch_RawDate);
```

Your code and some of the explanation mention other conditions.  To be honest, I don't follow them and this seems to produce what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
  Create table #table1( Emp_id  int, Card_Number int,  Dev_Id  int,  Dev_Direction varchar(20), 
  Punch_RawDate  datetime,         sno_id    int)

insert into #table1
select  1 ,     1   ,        1 , 'IN'    ,          '2021-02-01 16:52:26.000','331' union all
select  2 ,     2   ,        1 , 'IN'    ,          '2021-02-01 16:52:48.000','332' union all
select  2 ,     2   ,        2 , 'OUT'   ,          '2021-02-01 16:52:54.000','333' union all
select  3 ,     3   ,        1 , 'IN'    ,          '2021-02-01 16:58:01.000','334' union all
select  4 ,     4   ,        1 , 'IN'    ,          '2021-02-01 16:58:46.000','335' union all
select  3 ,     3   ,        2 , 'OUT'   ,          '2021-02-01 16:59:02.000','336' union all
select  4 ,     4   ,        2 , 'OUT'   ,          '2021-02-01 18:25:00.000','338' union all
select  1 ,     1   ,        2 , 'OUT'   ,          '2021-02-01 18:26:00.000','339'
```

Using self join and datediff function get the result

```
select b.* from #table1 a
join #table1 b on a.Emp_id=b.Emp_id and a.Dev_Direction='In' and b.Dev_Direction ='out'
and DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.Punch_RawDate, b.Punch_RawDate)>30
order by b.Emp_id
```